# RecyclerView Adapter and ViewHolder update dynamically

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I am trying to make an app that will be loading news from the network and will be updating dynamically. I am using a `RecyclerView` and `CardView` to display the content. I use `Jsoup` to parse sites. I don't think that my code is needed because my question is more theoretical than practical. I want to understand the process of dynamic updating using `notifyDataSetChanged()`. In my main activity I get all the headers and add them to list. But I need to wait untill all the items are loaded to start displaying them. I would really appreciate if someone could post a sample code of what I'm trying to do because I couldn't find a lot of information about combining `ViewHolder`, `Adapter` and `RecyclerView`.

Comment: can you post your adapter code here ....

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In your `RecyclerView adapter`, you should have a `ArrayList` and also one method `addItemsToList(items)` to add list items to the `ArrayList`. Then you can add list items by call `adapter.addItemsToList(items)` dynamically. After all your list items added to the `ArrayList` then you can call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to display your list.

Hope this is clear!

Comment: this part is clear, thank you. But how does it correspond with a ViewHolder?

Comment: `ViewHolder describes an item view and metadata about its place within the RecyclerView`. Your dynamical updating list no different with normal `ViewHolder`

Comment: I have figured out how to finish it. The only thing that you didn't mention is that the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` must be called in the UI thread. And to do that I used `runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){...})`

Comment: without your codes hard to know what process you are using to get your list items, seems you are using a thread to do that, but better you should use background thread `Asynctask` to get list items, then you can communicate with main UI in `onPostExecute(listItems)`

Comment: my code was a bit wrong as I had wrong parameters in `postExecute()`. But still using it in a separate thread inside AsyncTask is what I was looking for because it adds each item separately without waiting for all the list to load! And I think it might help me in future when I will have much more headers!

Comment: Yes `Asynctask` is much easier to use for downloading list items (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)