# How to update ListView when data fetched from Server

Tags: android, listview

This is how my `ListFragment` looks

```
public class TransactionListFragment extends ListFragment {
    private List<Transaction> mTransactions;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setTitle(R.string.transactions);
        mTransactions = Transactions.get(getActivity()).getTransactionsFromServer();

        ArrayAdapter<Transaction> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mTransactions);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

and `Transactions.get(getActivity()).getTransactionsFromServer();` looks like

```
private void getTransactionsFromServer() {
        final String url = "myURL";
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d("GET /Transactions:", response.toString());
                        generateTransactionCollectionFromResponse(response);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // handle error
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                headers.put("BEARER", "55b885274e7912280095ef80ac1cb937:d8922b44-75af-4810-a87e");
                return headers;
            }
        };

        queue.add(request);
    }

    private void generateTransactionCollectionFromResponse(JSONObject response) {
        JSONArray transactionsJson = null;
        try {
            transactionsJson = response.getJSONArray("transactions");
            Log.d("TransactionsJson:", transactionsJson.toString());

            for (int i = 0; i < transactionsJson.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject transactionJson = transactionsJson.getJSONObject(i);
                Transaction transaction = new Transaction(transactionJson.getString("id"), transactionJson.getString("name"));
                mTransactions.add(transaction);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Given that the task will happen asynchronously, the `ListView` would be empty initially.

**Question**

How do I indicate from my `Transactions` that reload the listView once I am done getting the results?

**UPDATE**
This is how `Transaction` is constructed

```
public class Transactions {
    private List<Transaction> mTransactions;
    private static Transactions sTransactions;
    private Context mContext;

    private Transactions(Context appContext) {
        mContext = appContext;
        mTransactions = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

**Question**
How can I get `Adapter` or `ListView`?

Comment: `((BaseAdapter)getListView().getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Comment: As you can see from my code `Transaction` has no reference to `ListView` or `Adapter`.  @Blackbelt, in `Transaction` class, `getListView()` is not found

Comment: The problem here is, If I'm not mistaken, to get a reference to the `Adapter` from an asynchronous method call, @Blackbelt What OP need to do is implement a callback method in `ListFragment`, e.g. an Interface?

Comment: @Selvin, I think it keeps a reference, but I could be wrong

Comment: I updated my question with what `Transaction` looks like. It does not have reference to `ListView` or `Adapter`

Comment: @daydreamer, I did the wrong assumption that your method was declared inside `TransactionListFragment`. One solution could be the delegate pattern through an interface, as suggested by @Marcus

Comment: or since your Transactions object as a context you could broadcast the an event, e.g "Data ready", and use a `BroadcastReceiver` to refresh the adapter's dataset

Comment: @Blackbelt, any example?

Comment: @Blackbelt that's two valid options. Someone should start typing an answer... And I'm too tierd :P

Comment: @Nickolaus also mentioned AsyncTask, which comes with an own callback method and runs on the UI thread, where an `ListView` update is possible. So: Delegation pattern, LocalBroadcast and AsyncTask is on the table.

Comment: for quick and dirty, I have passed `ListView` to `Transaction` and used `((BaseAdapter)getListView().getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged()` to update view and that works well, Thanks @Blackbelt

Comment: Check this post [Update ArrayList of adapter dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28539666/recyclerview-adapter-and-viewholder-update-dynamically/28540382#28540382)

Answer (score 2):

Quick easy/dirty solution could be to provide the `ListView` or the `Adapter` instance to the Transactions' constructor, and when you finish to parse the data, you can just call:

```
((BaseAdapter)mListView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

be aware that it has to run on the UI Thread.

Or,

### Solution using [LocalBroadcast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)

In your Fragment declare a `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {    
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    }
}
```

and an action for the `IntentFilter`

```
public static final String DATA_READY_ACTION = "DATA_READY_ACTION";
public MyBrodacastReceiver mReceiver;
```

you need to register and unregister it. You could use onResume to register it, onPause to unregister it:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(DATA_READY_ACTION));
```

to unregister

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
```

in your Transactions class, when the new data is available, you can BroadCast the event "Data Ready"

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(TransactionFragment.DATA_READY_ACTION);
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

When onReceive is fired you can update/refresh your `ListView`.

### Solution using an Interface

Let the Activity implement an interface,

```
public interface DataListener {
    public void onDataReceived(List<Transaction> t);
}
```

and pass a reference of the class that implements this interface, e.g. your ListFragment, to your `Transactions` class. After you finish to fill up your data, you can notify through this object, the event. E.g

```
private final DataListener mListener;
private Transactions(Context appContext, DataListener listener) {
    mContext = appContext;
    mListener = listener;
    mTransactions = new ArrayList<>();           
}

//.. fetch data code
if (mListener != null) {
    mListener.onDataReceived(mTransactions);
}
```

Please check for typo

Comment: Great, now add the solution using AsyncTask and Interfaces.. ;) +1

Comment: @Marcus the AsyncTask was not my idea :D

Comment: Your first suggestion seemed to do the trick. You should add that :P

Answer (score 0):

you should use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(),

more info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) which you can call in your on create method, then you can:

run `Transactions.get(getActivity()).getTransactionsFromServer();` in the `doInBackground` method 
and

create/update your *ListAdapter* in the `onPostExecute` method