# Updating Recycler Listview dynamically using Database

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I saw all the questions which is similar to my question ( in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367599/how-to-update-recyclerview-adapter-data) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28539666/recyclerview-adapter-and-viewholder-update-dynamically) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053610/best-way-to-update-data-with-a-recyclerview-adapter) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25306870/how-do-i-make-recyclerview-update-its-layout) link )

I had myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in my Activity but it doesn't work

I have 3 classes,

- DBHelper   -   For storing and getting Database contents ( NO ISSUES HERE )
- SimpleRecyclerAdapter - Adapter for RecyclerList
- ThirdActivity

> **What i did in ThirdActivity :**
>
> I have TextBox to get data and store it in Database and a Button.  In
>   the Onclicklistener of Button, i specified code to
>
> - get text from  textbox
> - add it into table using DBHelper
> - retrive data as ArrayList  from DBHelper
> - myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

When i click the Button, I **got Data in LogCat** which i specified inside OnclickListener but it is **not reflected to the listview.**

Here is my code,

**ThirdActivity:**

```
public class ThirdActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    DbHelper dbHelper;

    EditText et;
    Button addButton;
    RecyclerView rv;
    ArrayList<String> myNotesList;
    SimpleRecycler3Adapter adapter3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.thirdactivity);
        myNotesList = new ArrayList<>();
        et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
        addButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.dbListrv);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getBaseContext());
        rv.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

        adapter3 = new SimpleRecycler3Adapter(myNotesList);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter3);
        dbHelper = new DbHelper(this, null, null, 1);


        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("DB", "Constructor");
              String note=et.getText().toString();
             dbHelper.addNote(note);
               printData();
            }
        });
    }

    public void printData(){
        Log.d("DB","Constructor");
        myNotesList=dbHelper.databasetostring();
        Log.d("DB","Data came"+myNotesList.get(myNotesList.size()-1));
     //  adapter3 = new SimpleRecycler3Adapter(myNotesList);
       // rv.setAdapter(adapter3);
        adapter3.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**SimpleRecyclerViewAdapter :**

```
public class SimpleRecycler3Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleRecycler3Adapter.NotesHolder> {

private  ArrayList<String> myNotesList=new ArrayList<String>();

        String TAG="ThirdAdapter kbt";
        RecyclerView rv;

    public SimpleRecycler3Adapter(ArrayList<String> myList) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Constructor");

            Log.d(TAG,"Not null");
            int i = 0;
            while (i < myNotesList.size()) {
                myNotesList.add(myList.get(i).toString());
            }
            Log.d(TAG,"finish");
    }


    @Override
        public NotesHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
          Log.d(TAG,"On create started");
        View view2 = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerlist3_item, viewGroup, false);
        Log.d(TAG,"ADAP STAR ONCR second switch 2nd line");
        NotesHolder viewHolder2 = new NotesHolder(view2);
        Log.d(TAG,"ADAP STAR ONCR second switch 3nd line");
        return viewHolder2;
        }

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(NotesHolder notesHolder, int i) {
        Log.d(TAG, "ONBIND SECOND i value is " + i);


        // notesHolder.thumbnail.setImageResource(R.drawable.placeholder);

        notesHolder.dblistitem.setText(myNotesList.get(i));
          Log.d(TAG,"ONBIND second title issssss");


        }


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
        return myNotesList.size();
        }

class NotesHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected ImageView thumbnail;
    protected TextView dblistitem;
    public NotesHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        Log.d(TAG, "JSON Inside HOLDER");
        rv=(RecyclerView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.dbListrv);
      //  thumbnail = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        dblistitem = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dblistitem);


    }

}

}
```

Comment: Where do you retrive data as ArrayList from DBHelper?Why should you use myNotesList 2times?

Comment: In third Activity  , inside printData() method at this line ` myNotesList=dbHelper.databasetostring();` where printData() method is called at Button Click Listener

Comment: Can you change private  ArrayList<String> myNotesList=new ArrayList<String>() => private  ArrayList<String> myNotesList2=new ArrayList<String>()?

Comment: @tiny sunlight : What is the use of changing variable name ? I am not getting you. :-\

Comment: I added a answer.You will confused youself if you use same variable name.

Comment: @Santiago Hernández is right.

Comment: you should use [this](https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b) adapter, your life will be easier

Comment: Why don't you just try      //  adapter3 = new SimpleRecycler3Adapter(myNotesList);
       // rv.setAdapter(adapter3)?

Comment: Can you  update your code  after using Santiago'code?

Comment: @tinysunlight When i use that it works.. wow b4 it didn't worked thats why i  hided. But is it good practice to initialize it each time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not updating the myNotesList that is in adapter class but in activity class. But the adapter uses it's local myNotesList.

So on button click, update myNotesList of adapter with latest data available and notify the adapter.

**EDIT**
Pass the latest data to adapter. Have this method in adapter class and call this before notifyDataSetChanged();

```
public void updateNotes(ArrayList<String> notesList) {
    myNotesList = notesList; 
}
```

Comment: How can i update it again, do i need to initialize again and again while inserting each element ? Or is there any way to update it. ?

Comment: You just need to pass the latest data to adapter. Have this method in adapter class and call this before notifyDataSetChanged();

public void updateNotes(ArrayList<String> notesList) {
        myNotesList = notesList;
    }

Comment: I'll try it out and say you what is the result.

Comment: good. You do not need to vote up any answer before you make sure it helps you. It may lead to confusion for other seekers. :)
You can accept answer.

Comment: They tried giving answers for me , i just appreciated and it made sense. Actually what they specified is correct (Generally nor for my answer ) That's why i up voted . Anyway... Thanks alot for the answer. I was sitting for 2 days with this error. lol... u solved it.  Thanks again

Comment: Sure, makes sense for me too..not discouraging you. It's good you do that so they get boost ;)
ha ha..2 days ;)

Comment: Yeah. I can't even get this simple idea :( My poor brain.

Answer (score 1):

1.you are intializing your dbhelper after setting adapter to listview so it couldn't contain any data initially

2.for updating recycler view data list do as follows

```
myNotesList.clear();
myNotesList.addAll(dbHelper.databasetostring());
adapter3.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: 1. Do i need to initialize before ?

2. If i do like that, i need to reload all the data whenever i add an item to listview.

Comment: Adding one item to the listview is better than reloading all the items for insertion of single item ? Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: you are correct. use adapter3.notifyItemInserted(position); for updating particular item.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in your **SimpleRecyclerViewAdapter**, just change this:

```
while (i < myNotesList.size()) {
    myNotesList.add(myList.get(i).toString());
}
```

For this:

```
myNotesList = myList;
```

And in your **activity**'s `printData()` change:

```
myNotesList=dbHelper.databasetostring();
```

for this:

```
myNotesList.clear();
myNotesList.addAll(dbHelper.databasetostring());
adapter3.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**Explanation:**

First you initialize `myNotesList` variable:

```
myNotesList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then you initialize `adapter3`

```
adapter3 = new SimpleRecycler3Adapter(myNotesList);
```

But your adapter is not saving the reference, instead you're copying its data into another variable:

```
while (i < myNotesList.size()) {
    myNotesList.add(myList.get(i).toString());
}
```

Doing that, if you change `myNotesList` variable in your `activity` will not modify your adapter's dataset.

In your method `printData()` you change `myNotesList` variable. Which will not touch your adapter or its data

```
public void printData(){
    Log.d("DB","Constructor");
    myNotesList=dbHelper.databasetostring();
    Log.d("DB","Data came"+myNotesList.get(myNotesList.size()-1));
    //  adapter3 = new SimpleRecycler3Adapter(myNotesList);
    // rv.setAdapter(adapter3);
    adapter3.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: So what changes i should do in my code to update my list?

Comment: Hi Ganesh, just put `myNotesList = myList;` instead of your `while`. This is in your `SimpleRecycler3Adapter`'s constructor and that's it

Comment: While initializing only Adapter's constructor is called. After that note even a single time it is called as well as onBind onCreateViewHolder is also not called

Comment: I think it's because `dbHelper.databasetostring();` is returning a new `ArrayList` instance too

Comment: Inside printData() i hided 2 lines. I un-hided it and the code works. I assume the method which you specified above will work, which one i should prefer. Which is the best practice, **initializing and setting adapter each time** or **your method**?

Comment: initializing an adapter every time the user tap on a button is not a good practice, that's why it's called `Recycler`

Comment: I changed the two things which you specified above, but i can't see the list again.

Comment: I  think you just need chang 1 place .where are the 2 places?

Comment: I got to go to sleep Ganesh, but good luck with that. I suggest you to declare a [setter](http://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview/) in your `adapter` so you can set the new `dataset` and call `notifyDataSetChanged` after setting it

Comment: I mean in Adapter  and printData ()  , anyhow cgr answer worked for me. Calling another method of Adapter for initialization purpose from ThirdActivity.

Comment: Look at comment of cgr's Answer, That one is good practice , isn't that?

Comment: actually yes it is :), that's the best way to go

Comment: @SantiagoHernández Anyhow , thanks a lot for your explanation and effort for me.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't change myNotesList by changing myList.

```
   public SimpleRecycler3Adapter(ArrayList<String> myList) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Constructor");

            Log.d(TAG,"Not null");
          //  int i = 0;
           // while (i < myNotesList.size()) {
          //      myNotesList.add(myList.get(i).toString());
          //  }
            this.myNotesList = myList;
            Log.d(TAG,"finish");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'll try it out and say .

Answer (score 0):

Not a good idea to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` when you know exactly what changed in your data collection.
See this implementation [here](https://github.com/aneophyte/Dynamic-Data-Binding-for-RecyclerView/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/sample/databindingsample/adapter/ArrayMapAdapter.java).
They have even documented to use `notifyDataSetChanged()` as a last resort in this [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29).

You get nice animations for free if you use methods like `notifyItemInserted()` and the rest.

Also do not go on replacing the collection object entirely, see the implmentation link that has been attached.